# Linux Mint app / applet / extension to control active window by moving cursor to screen corners

Tags: linux, open-source, user-interface, window-manager, desktop-environment

I remember recently using a Linux app, applet, or extension that allowed the user to define actions for each corner of the screen (monitor).  It was very simple to use, and had options for each screen corner including *minimise* (*minimize*), *maximise* (*maximize*), and *close window*.  Simply moving the cursor to a corner of the screen would perform the desired action (no clicking required).  The user could define a different action for each corner of the display.

It was similar to Linux Mint's `Hot Corners` app, but included the pre-defined functions mentioned above.

I thought it was available via Linux Mint's `Extensions` app (whose data is reflected on https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/extensions), but I'm not seeing it there.  Another possibility is that it was available or included with Elementary OS.

Can anyone recommend such a tool for Linux Mint?  It must be gratis and open-source.

Answer (score 1):

With Linux Mint's Hot Corners you can use `Run a command` (It's in the hot corners menu). All you have to do is install xdotool.

**xdotool** lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc.

```
sudo apt install xdotool

man xdotool
```

Tested with Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon

**minimize** ; You can try this command :

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowminimize
```

**maximize**

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Alt+F10
```

**close**

```
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Alt+F4
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  That works great most of the time.  For some odd reason, windows will now occasionally get larger than the screen, or not maximize to the full size of the screen.  Any idea how to resolve that?

Comment: Given that you are experienced with `xdotool`, do you know why running the following command does not work to minimize an open Bluefish Editor window? `xdotool search --name 'bluefish' windowminimize`

Comment: This works for me with bluefish: `xdotool search --name 'bluefish' windowminimize %@`   (%@ = current window, not necessarily with focus). I'll check for maximize.

Comment: That works from the terminal. Thank you! Why is the `%@` needed?  Also, do you why doesn't it work when added as a command in the Startup Applications app?

Comment: I've updated the command to maximize. Not sure why the `%@` is sometimes needed with search. What command do you use at startup? I think you have to start bluefish first.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes, I launch Bluefish first, wait for it to fully load, then try to run the following command, but it has no effect: `xdotool search --name 'bluefish' windowminimize`